# how to define normal javascript function inside the controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code snippet below.

sample.js

```
(function() {
    /*global angular */
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp', ['spinner'])
       .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window ) {

    $scope.methodname = function() {
            if(something){
                /* Doing some operations */
            }
    };
    /* Here I need to define the callme javascript function */

   function callme(response){
       /* If I call like this, I'm getting error in console. */
    }

    }]);  /* Controller ends here */

    /* Creating a new anonymous function to perform some operations */
    (function () {
    'use strict';


     /* Edited */
   code.util.myHTTP(url, function (response) {

             // Adding response to session storage
            callme(response);

             }, function () {
               // Removing from session storage
        });

        })();
     }());
```

Here, I can't able to call callme javascript function inside angular controller . I'm getting error in console like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: callme is not defined
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I need to use some controller parameters like $window inside callme function, that's why I'm defining callme function inside controller.

I have run function in my js file already like below

```
.run(function($rootScope, $log, $window) {
});
```

My requirement is like call anonymous function, on load there will be some api response, I need to call one method to process the response. because of these controller parameters, I wanted to define my method inside the controller. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: The logic is off. Either define `callme` outside of the controller (you'll still be able to call it from the controller), or inside the other scope you created.

Comment: then if I call callme outside the controller, how can I use $scope?

Comment: You can pass `$scope` as argument to `callme` as you pass any other variable. (e.g. in the controller: `callme($scope, response);`).

Comment: @ShadowWizard that won't work because `core.util.myHTTP` has no reference to `$scope` at the call site. OP has an XY problem and what he wants will never work.

Comment: OP, Angular tries to make you do everything "the angular way". Why do you need to execute http outside of Angular and then call stuff inside Angular as a result? Why can you not do everything inside of the Angular framework, as you're meant to do? As much as I dislike Angular's templates, if you are fighting to do something in Angular, it generally means you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Dan but bottom line, $scope is a JavaScript object, not some magic. I'm pretty sure I did something like that in the past and it worked. If needed, I'll test it again to confirm. (and for the record, you can use `@UI_Dev` here to address the OP, it won't be sripped since there are several users commenting)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, you're actually wrong here. You need an instance of scope itself, not a JavaScript object, for this to work. If you let OP do this now, any changes he makes to the $scope object will **not** be picked up by Angular. Scope *may* be an object, but you can't just pass a random object in place of a scope and hope it works. It *needs* to be a child of `$rootScope` via `$rootScope.$new()`, and you aren't going to get that outside of the angular framework. Also, I know I can ping him, I just prefer OP :)

Comment: callme function is declaring inside anonymous function. I cannot use $scope there

Comment: Please explain why you need to call this function inside of an anonymous function and not inside of the Angular framework? I'm struggling to see a reason for it.

Comment: the reason is these anonymous function should be loaded on page load to check value (first time there is no value sometimes) and after there will be some click event will happen, then again this anonymous function will call and check for the value, this time value presents, then callme function is called

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do this in `.run()` or inside of a component at the top of your component tree in Angular?

Comment: can I use  this anonymous function inside run? and can i call callme function too?

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is all over the place and is what makes this code hard to understand. Here's your correctly formatted code..

```
(function () {
  /*global angular */
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myapp', ['spinner'])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
      $scope.methodname = function () {
        if (something) {
          /* Doing some operations */
        }
      };
      /* Here I need to define the callme javascript function */

      function callme (response) {
        /* If I call like this, I'm getting error in console. */

      }
    }]); /* Controller ends here */

  /* Creating a new anonymous function to perform some operations */
  (function () {
    'use strict';

    /* Edited */
    code.util.myHTTP(url, function (response) {

      // Adding response to session storage
      callme(response);
    }, function () {
      // Removing from session storage
    });
  })();
}());
```

The reason this doesn't work is because `function` declarations are *hoisted* to the top of their scope, but do not exist outside of that scope. If we remove some cruft, this is what your code simplifies to:

```
(function() {
  function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.methodname = function() {}

    function callme(response) {
    }
  }

  (function() {
    callme()
  }())
}())
```

`callme` is hoisted, but only to the top of `MyController`. That symbol doesn't exist outside of that scope, and that's why you can't do `callme()` in your nested scope.

What you are doing seems like an anti-pattern; even if you could achieve this, `core.util.myHTTP` would not execute within the Angular digest cycle, so you'd have to call `$scope.$apply` inside of your controller, which is generally considered a bad thing. Why not just use `$http` instead?

Nevertheless, if you *really* want to do this (and you don't), you could define your function like so:

```
(function() {
  function callme(response) { }

  function MyController($scope) {}

  (function() {
    ...
    callme()
  }())
}())
```

Alternatively you could use directives (or components, depending on your angular version) to handle this instead.. which is how it should be done.

```
function SpinnerCtrl($http) {
  this.$http = $http
}
SpinnerCtrl.$inject = ['$http']
SpinnerCtrl.onInit = function onInit() {
  var that = this
  return this.$http.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      // Store it in session storage, do whatever.
      // Presumably there's some data you want to make accessible to other parts of the app, so I assign it to the controller here
      that.response = response
    })
}

angular.module('myapp', ['spinner'])
  .component('spinner', {
    controller: SpinnerCtrl,
    template: '<h1>{{ $ctrl.response }}</h1>'
  })

// or

function SpinnerCtrl($scope, $http) {
  return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
    $scope.response = response
  })
}

angular.module('myapp', ['spinner'])
  .directive('spinner', function () {
    return {
      controller: SpinnerCtrl,
      template: '<h1>{{ response }}</h1>'
    }
  })
```

Note that really you should move the $http call to a service and handle the session storage in there too; the session storage thing is implementation detail and the component/directive using it should not have to care. I haven't done that just for brevity.

Comment: lets take methodname is called when there is any click event. this callme function is calling after getting the response from click event. in this case, will this code work?

Comment: Uh, yes, I suppose? But in that case why does the `callme` function need to be located outside of the controller? Why can't it be colocated? I'm struggling to see why you need to layout your code in this manner. Your insistence on calling the $http call outside of the Angular cycle is causing you a lot of headaches here. Can you justify it?

Comment: can I use this anonymous function inside run? and can i call callme function too?